# Htaccess rewrite rule parameter to page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have page http://mysite.ru/test/abc.html and I would like that it will be accessable by url http://mysite.ru/?param=abc.html
I tried to use rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^/?param=(.*)$ /test/$1
```

but it doesn't work. Please help what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /test/%1? [L,R]
```